# What's the best tool for cutting holes into duct work?

Tags: hvac

I've cut a few supply and cold air returns into my main branches and it's been a PITA. Need to cut another 6" hole for a return, it's just standard rectangle ductwork, probably 14" wide x 10" high.

Comment: What did you use last time, and what made it a PITA?

Comment: Tried a few things, a hole saw  (best option so far but it wasn't large enough so I had to cut it again), angle grinder (not good curvature and metal shavings all over), started a hole with drill bit and then went around with aviation snips (did not track well and deformed the metal). Just seeing if there's a common method for circular holes for a collar.

Comment: Protip: Cut away, fold away, or cover all shards left behind from your cut. I'm currently healing from a full-depth finger slice on someone else's work, which was hidden behind a duct connector.

Comment: Also when cutting only turn your attack angle while squeezing the snips, never go back to make a turn or adjustment. If you do you will end up with very sharp curled up pieces of metal colloquially known as meat hooks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibbler

Comment: For 6" you probably want a circle cutter.

Comment: Anyone want to address "why not a Dremel?" which would be my first go-to for something like this...

Comment: @R.. Wouldn't that be a bit small for a 6" hole? It would definitely help with getting rid of the sharp edges afterwards though.

Comment: @Mast: Not as a drill. They have lots of different attachments including metal cutting discs. Slow for cutting through something hard and thick like iron pipes (but I've done this and it works), but fast on soft and thin metals.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**STEP ONE**

Using a big flat screwdriver orienteded edgewise and a hammer. Strike the screwdriver swiftly and accurately to puncture the duct.
[image]

**STEP TWO**

Insert a Red pair of snips into the hole and nibble around turning to the left (Greens are pictured only because that's what was in front of me) in an expanding circle until you get to the line.
[image]

**STEP THREE**

Cut along your line all the way to the corner, with force turn and continue while gently pulling up on the scrap. Every 2-3 inches turn in off the line and make a relief cut and go back to the line. Once you get to the next corner you don't need relief cuts anymore.
[image]

**COMPLETE THE CUT**
Now it's easy, just cut along the line gently pulling up the scrap. If you are left handed, or only have greens feel free to use Greens but reverse the images. Yellows are designed to cut straight but are capable of cutting to the left like Reds

**FOR CIRCULAR HOLES**

The same process applies just without the relief cuts.

Comment: The best tool is a plasma cutter. Fast and clean but not many homeowners are going to shell out +1K for this type of cutting tool.

Comment: harbor fright sells cutters for about half that. probably not the biggest workhorse around, but should be enough for duct work...

Comment: Life's too short not to own a plasma cutter.

Comment: @Sidney the last time I seriously looked into buying one was about 15 years ago when I was still dumb enough to jump off of ladders. They were big, expensive and didn't offer a good quality cut. Thanks to this question I am back on the search.

Comment: What's the difference between red, yellow and green snips? How would this translate internationally?

Comment: @Mast A yellow cutter cuts in a straight line, a red one is designed for cutting toward the left, and a green one cuts toward the right. In this case, in the cutting direction shown in the pictures, a "red" - i.e. left curved - snip will leave a clean right edge and a messy left edge, but the left edge doesn't matter because you are removing that piece. The reason not to use a "yellow" - i.e. straight - snip here is because you don't have room to work with it because the metal doesn't move out of the way of the body of the tool....

Comment: @Mast ... I have no idea if the colors are the same internationally, and there are probably even some North American tools that don't follow these colors.

Comment: If they don't they're not made by Wiss and they're crap.

Answer (score 8):

You might be able to rent a tool from a rental yard called a "nibbler"; you would start with a drilled hole and then the nibbler takes little semi-circular or rectangular bites out of the sheet metal. There are also inexpensive ones now that attach to a drill motor, one is shown in this video. He has troubles with it because he is trying to use it on corrugated sheet metal, you would not have that issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt4O62qnHsk

Comment: That things actually pretty cool and looks inexpensive. I have several other styles but I think I may buy this one. +1

Comment: 15 Canadian dollars! Sold one click purchase.

Comment: Air shear are also very similar to a nibbler and inexpensive but usually air driven. ~30 CAD

Comment: As a tin banger snips are still the best, fastest and most accurate way to cut. But as I've gotten older I've been reaching for the power shears due to golfers/tennis elbow in both my arms. I used to be able to literally crush a walnut in my hand. Now I can barely hold a cup at times. I'm only 37.

Comment: Ah, an *Electric* nibbler. The hand powered ones used to cut holes for switches in metal plate, would work, but would take roughly 1 year per hole. Don't get the manual tool for holes that size.

Comment: When using a circle cutter, there's a direction you must go and an angle that's ideal to hold it at;  you'll know when you find it.

Answer (score 0):

Square holes can easily be cut with an angle grinder and a thin cut off wheel

Comment: The OP mentioned this (in a comment, not in a question, which is why that kind of info should be in the question, not a comment) and included it in his list of things not wanting to try again.